# Uploading data in Blackberry using POST method in HTTPS

Tags: java, blackberry, post, https

I am trying to figure out how to upload a data using HTTPS POST method in Blackberry. The following code worked well when i tried it on HTTP. I just want to know what did i miss here

```
            String _postData = "LATITUDE="+lat+"&LONGITUDE="+lng+"&"+"NAME="+name+"&NRIC="+ICNo+"&PLATENO="+VehicleNo+"&CONTACTNO="+ContactNo+"&LOCATION="+ADDRESS;
            OutputStream os;

            //the preferred network is already arranged here
            int[] preferredTransportTypes = {TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR};
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setPreferredTransportTypes(preferredTransportTypes);

            ConnectionDescriptor connDescriptor = factory.getConnection("https://example.com");
            if(connDescriptor==null){
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Dialog.alert("Invalid Network. Please check your network set up.");

                    }
                });
            }else{

                final HttpsConnection https = (HttpsConnection) connDescriptor.getConnection();

                https.setRequestMethod(HttpsConnection.POST);
                byte [] postDataBytes = _postData.getBytes("UTF8");   
                `enter code here`https.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
                https.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                https.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                os = https.openOutputStream();
                os.write(postDataBytes);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                int state= https.getResponseCode();

                if(state==HttpsConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {                      
                            Dialog.alert("SOS sent. Our customer care personnel will contact you shortly.");

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {                      
                            Dialog.alert("Failed to send SOS .");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {}
```

When the above code was executed, the application received HttpsConnection.HTTP_OK and show the dialog that the SOS was sent. But the data is not uploaded in the server.

Comment: You are throwing away your exceptions there, have you tried catching them and printing them out to see if there are any? It's possible that you don't have a library that is required for HTTPS communication.

Comment: Yeah, there is no exception occured. I checked the content of postDataBytes, i checked if os.write() will throw an exception, i already set the content-type and all seems fine.

Comment: I believe there are other places where exceptions can be thrown. Have you tried just changing your catch to: catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }